# switch not working as expected

Tags: java, sorting, switch-statement

I'm not sure why, but my program isn't working as it should.  `quickSort()` and `mergeSort()` seem to execute two times on each array size.  This is the first time I have tried using a switch so i suspect it has something to do with that.

the purpose of this program is to benchmark 4 sorting methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //top line of excel spreadsheet
    String CSVString = "data size (100 times),bubble,insertion,merge,quick,,fastest,slowest\n";

    //how many elements in array to be sorted?
    int sizes[] = {10000, 20000, 100000, 200000, 1000000, 2000000};
    //used for min and max formulas in excel
    int rowNumber = 2;
    //sort each array with 4 sorting algorithms
    for (int size : sizes) {
        CSVString = sortRandomSet(size, CSVString, rowNumber);
        rowNumber++;
    }
    System.out.println("Writing data to benchmark.csv"
            + "\nNote that numbers higher than 99999 are not accurate");

    writeCSV(CSVString);
}//end main()


/**
 * *************************** sortRandomSet method
 * ************************** This method sorts an array with 4 sorting
 * methods (100 times each) Each sort is timed and added to a string for
 * outputting in CSV file CSVString is returned Last edited by Steve Pesce
 * 4/1/2014
 */
public static String sortRandomSet(int setSize, String CSVString, int rN) throws Exception {
    //this is the total time in seconds that it takes to sort the array 100 times
    double[] time = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    //these are used for calculating time[] time[x] = duration = end - start time
    long startTime;

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        //this for loop uses each sorting algorithm and times them each
        for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
            //new array and temp array of same size
            int[] randSet = new int[setSize];
            int[] temp = new int[randSet.length];
            //to show current progress
            System.out.print(k + "% done sorting " + setSize + " elements ");
            for (int i = 0; i < randSet.length; i++) {
                //fill array with random numbers
                randSet[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
            }
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            //switch that executes in relation to j in this for loop
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    if (setSize < 100000)//this is where bubble takes too long
                    {
                        bubbleSort(randSet);
                        System.out.println("with bubble sort\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        time[j] = 9999;//set time to high value if sort skipped
                    }
                case 1:
                    if (setSize < 100000)//this is where insert takes too long
                    {
                        insertionSort(randSet);
                        System.out.println("with insertion sort\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        time[j] = 9999;//set time to high value if sort skipped
                    }
                case 2:
                    mergeSort(randSet, temp, 0, (randSet.length - 1));
                    System.out.println("with merge sort\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    quickSort(randSet, 0, randSet.length - 1);
                    System.out.println("with quick sort\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                    break;
                //calculate duration of sort and add to overall duration
            }
            time[j] = time[j] + ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0);
            //dont let time go over 9999
            if (time[j] > 9999) {
                time[j] = 9999;
            }
        }//end for
    }

    String maxMin;
    //used to put max and min functions in excel cells
    maxMin = ",,=min(b" + rN + ":e" + rN + "),=max(b" + rN + ":e" + rN + ")";

    //append new data to CSVString
    CSVString = (CSVString + setSize + "," + time[0] + "," + time[1] + "," + time[2] + ","
            + time[3] + maxMin + "\n");

    return CSVString;

}//end sortRandomSet()
```

Comment: Are you missing `break` statements in the `else` clauses of your `if`s in `case 0` and `case 1` or that's the way your algorithm work?

Comment: You are not breaking in the 'else' clauses

Comment: This is some really messy code that can be simplified.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc care to elaborate?

Comment: @user2809114:  If you have clauses that do the same thing, then you can refactor it so that have less repeated clauses.  Also, the inconsistent spacing makes it very difficult to read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, simplified:

```
case 0:
    if (aBoolean)
    {
        break;
    } else {

    }
case 1:
    if (anotherBoolean)
    {
        break;
    } else {

    }
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
```

The `break;` statements for cases 0 and 1 only execute if `aBoolean` and `anotherBoolean` are true. When one of them is false, the break statement is not executed, and the code inside the *entire* switch statement begins to execute starting at that case statement.

To fix it, put the break statements right before the next case:

```
case 0:
    if (aBoolean)
    {

    } else {

    }
    break;
case 1:
    if (anotherBoolean)
    {

    } else {

    }
    break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
```